Generic intersection of hyperplanes
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and $V_1,\cdots,V_n$ be subspaces of $V$. My main question is

Prove that $$f:\bigoplus_{i=1}^n V_i\to V^n/\Delta$$ is surjective, where the map is induced by inclusions $V_i\to V$ and $\Delta$ is the diagonal $\Delta= \{ (v,\cdots,v),v\in V \} \in V^n$, if and only if $V$ have a direct sum decomposition $V=L\oplus L_1\oplus\cdots\oplus L_n$(the summands are allowed to be $0$) so that $$V_i=L\oplus L_1\oplus\cdots L_{i-1}\oplus L_{i+1}\oplus\cdots L_n$$

Some Backgrounds:
When $f$ is surjective, we also say $\{V_i\}$ intersect generically, since this condition is equivalent to " given arbitrary vectors $a_i\in V$, we can find $v_i\in V_i$ and $v\in V$, so that $$v_i+a_i=v$$ This means if we move the planes $\{V_i\}$ a little $a_i$, they still intersect at some point $v$.
More backgrounds(Not needed to solving this linear algebra problem): manifold version
In many interesting cases in differential geometry, we need to compactify configuration spaces, and they are done by blowing up submanifolds successively. It turns out that if these submanifolds intersect generically, then the order you perform to blow up these submanifolds doesn't effect the result of compactification (Dylan Thurston's thesis). This question is local linearized version.

If $m$ is the dimension of $V,$ then $nm-m$ is the dimension of $V^n/\Delta$ so if the function is onto, the average dimension of the $V_i$ is going to be $m-1.$ That doesn't give a lot of wiggle room.

Do you also want the assumption that $$V=L\oplus L_1\oplus L_2\oplus\ldots \oplus L_n?$$ Without that, it looks like we can just take $V_i, L_i,L$ all to be ${0}$ and get a counterexample.

@user469053, You are right! Thanks! I forgot to add that assumption.

$\Rightarrow$: Existence of decomposition
Take $L = V_1 \cap \cdots \cap V_n$. For each $i = 1, \cdots, n$, take $L_i$ such that
$$L \oplus L_i = V_1 \cap \cdots \widehat{V_i} \cap \cdots \cap V_n$$
(It's possible that $L_i = 0$).
Lemma The sum $L + L_1 + \cdots + L_n$ is direct.
Proof Suppose $l \in L$, $l_i \in L_i$, such that
$$l + l_1 + \cdots + l_n = 0.$$
As an example, consider the index 1. By definition, for $j \neq 1$,
$$L_j \subset V_1 \cap \cdots \widehat{V_j} \cap \cdots \cap V_n \subset V_1.$$
So $l + l_2 + \cdots + l_n \in V_1$. Hence
$$l_1 = -(l + l_2 + \cdots + l_n) \in V_1.$$
But then
$$l_1 \in L_1 \cap V_1 = (L_1 \cap \widehat{V_1} \cap \cdots \cap V_n) \cap V_1 = L_1 \cap (V_1 \cap \cdots \cap V_n) = L_1 \cap L = 0,$$
since we chose $L_1$ to be direct with $L$ to start with. Thus $l_1 = 0$. Similarly, $l_2 = \cdots = l_n = 0$. Hence $l = 0$ as well. (QED for lemma)
Note that so far we have not used surjectivity of $f$.
Claim 1 For each $i$,
$$V_i = L + L_1 + \cdots + \widehat{L_i} + \cdots + L_n.$$
Proof Again as an example, consider the index 1, and consider $x \in V_1$.

Take $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) = (0, x, 0, \cdots, 0)$. Surjectivity of $f$ implies that there exists $v_i \in V_i$ such that $x = v - v_2$ and $0 = v - v_j$ for $j \neq 2$. The latter condition implies that $v \in V_1 \cap \widehat{V_2} \cap \cdots \cap V_n$; write $v = l_2 + l$, with $l_2 \in L_2$ and $l \in L$. The former implies that $v_2 = v - x$; the right hand side is in $V_1$, since both $v$ and $x$ are. Hence $v_2 \in V_1 \cap V_2$. Setting $u_2 = l - v_2 \in V_1 \cap V_2$, we see that
$$x = l_2 + u_2$$
for some $l_2 \in L_2$ and $u_2 \in V_1 \cap V_2$.
Next, take $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) = (0, 0, u_2, 0, \cdots, 0)$. Surjectivity of $f$ implies that there exists $v_i \in V_i$ such that $u_2 = v - v_3$ and $0 = v - v_j$ for $j \neq 3$. The latter condition impleis that $V_1 \cap \widehat{V_3} \cap \cdots \cap V_n$; write $v_3 = l_3 + l$ with $l_3 \in L_3$ and $l \in L$. The former implies that $v_3 = v - u_2$; the right hand side is in $V_1 \cap V_2$, since both $v, u_2$ are. Hence $v_3 \in V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3$. Setting $u_3 = l - v_3 \in V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3$, we see that
$$u_2 = l_3 + u_3$$
for some $l_3 \in L_3$ and $u_3 \in V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3$.

Iterate this argument, we see that
$$x = l_2 + l_3 + \cdots + l_n + u_n$$
for $l_i \in L_i$, and $u_n \in V_1 \cap V_2 \cap \cdots \cap V_n = L$. This proves Claim 1.
Claim 2
$$V = L + L_1 + \cdots + L_n.$$
Proof We proceed in the same way as Claim 1. For $x \in V$, take $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) = (x, 0, \cdots, 0)$. Surjectivity of $f$ implies that there exists $v_i \in V_i$ such that $x = v - v_1$ and $0 = v - v_j$ for $j \neq 1$. The latter condition implies that $v \in V_2 \cap \cdots \cap V_n$; write $v = l_1 + l$ for some $l_1 \in L_1$, $l \in L$. Set $u_1 = l - v_1 \in V_1$, we see that
$$x = l_1 + u_1$$
for some $l_1 \in L_1$ and $u_1 \in V_1$. Now apply Claim 1 to write
$$u_1 = l_2 + \cdots + l_n + l$$
for $l_i \in L_i$, and $l \in L$. Hence
$$x = l_1 + \cdots + l_n + l$$
as desired.
These two claims show that $L, L_1, \cdots, L_n$ gives the desired decomposition for $V$ and $V_1, \cdots, V_n$.
$\Leftarrow$: Surjectivity of $f$
Given $(a_1, \cdots, a_n) \in V^n$, we want to find $(v_1, \cdots, v_n) \in V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n$, and $v \in V$, such that
$$v_i + a_i = v$$
for all $i$.
Given the decomposition $V = L \oplus L_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus L_n$, for each $i$ we write
$$a_i = l_i + \sum_{j=1}^n l_{ij}$$
where $l_i \in L$, and $l_{ij} \in L_j$.
Now take $v = \sum_{j=1}^n l_{jj}$. Then for each $i$, $v - a_i$ does not have the $L_i$ component, and hence lies in $V_i$. This shows surjectivity of $f$ as desired.

Why “The latter implies $v\in L_2$”?

Good catch, updated. It's only true that $v \in V_1 \cap \widehat{V_2} \cap \cdots \cap V_n$, but you can use the decomposition $L_2 \oplus L$ to extract the $L_2$ part, and the rest of the argument is unaffected.

Claim2 can be proved by an easier argument: this is equivalent to $\sum_jV_j=V$, which is trivial by surjectivity of $f$?

I don't see how $\sum_j V_j = V$ is trivial by surjectivity of $f$, but if you have a quick proof in mind then yes.

If some $a\notin \sum_j V_j$, then set $(a,0,\cdots,0)$ and we can solve $v_1+a=v$ where $v\in \bigcap_{j\neq 1}V_j$ and $v_1\in V_1$. In fact, I see the generic intersection is actually equivalent to $\bigcap_{j\neq k}V_j+V_k=V$ for each $k$

That's correct, and is exactly how I proceeded with the proof in Claim 2 as well. The rest of proof of Claim 2 is showing the "equivalence to $\sum_j V_j = V$" that you mentioned.
